# nginx 502 bad gateway error

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

I just switched from apache2 to nginx for one of my application that might hold a large traffic.

I have installed php-fastcgi, and earlier a test page with `phpinfo();` function worked properly. I have a small piece of snapshot as well.

[image: phpinfo snapshot]

I can't figure out how to make it work!

Here is what my nginx error logs says:

```
2012/04/24 16:21:18 [error] 5951#0: *1 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.1.6, server: 192.168.1.4, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "192.168.1.4:81"
2012/04/24 16:21:19 [error] 5951#0: *1 open() "/home/hitesh/brainlab/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.1.6, server: 192.168.1.4, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.1.4:81"
```

UPDATE : I rebooted the server and there is some new log msg right now;

```
2012/04/24 16:31:53 [error] 765#0: *3 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.1.6, server: 192.168.1.4, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "192.168.1.4:81"
2012/04/24 16:31:54 [error] 765#0: *3 open() "/home/hitesh/brainlab/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.1.6, server: 192.168.1.4, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.1.4:81"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use php-fpm *not* fastcgi with nginx. There's lots of doc out there on how to set it up, it's pretty simple.

Comment: Thanks, looked for 'lots of doc out there' got some and it was helpful.